# Enviar texto cuando una consulta a bd no envie resultados en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stored-procedure

Tengo un sp que envía datos, en algunas ocasiones no envía por que no existen datos, entonces quisiera poder mostrar en mi view un texto como "Aun no cuentas con registros" cuando no envie datos este stored y cuando si envie mostrarlos en la view.

En mi controller ya logro identificar cuando hay datos se envien y cuando no existan datos se envie mi mensaje a la view en una variable mediante array.
En mi view tengo condicionado mediante un if que verifique si mi variable mensaje esta declarada esta se muestre y si no, se hagan mis consultas a los resultados del stored.

Sin embargo se sigue ejecutando las consultas al stored a pesar de que va mi mensaje. Y me envía un error:

```
Attempt to read property "PeriodoAct" on string
```

Codigo en mi view

```
                    @if (isset($mensaje))
                    <p>{{ $mensaje }}</p>
                @else
                    @foreach($ston as $stone)
                        {{$stone[0]->PeriodoAct}} <br>
                        {{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stone[0]->Fecha)) }}<br>
                       {{$stone[0]->Concep}}<br>
                        {{ number_format($stone[0]->Import, 1, '.', '') }}<br>
                        {{$stone[0]->Status}}<br>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
```

Codigo de mi controller

```
 $ston = DB::select('{call MegaData(?, ?, ?)}', array($Id, $Act, $Periodo));
        if (empty($ston)) {
        $mensaje = 'Aun no cuentas con registros';
        $ston = ['mensaje' => $mensaje];
    } else {
        $ston = ['ston' => $ston];
    }
    $data = [
        'suc' => $ksuc,
        'per' => $per,
        'ston' => $ston
    ];
    // dd($data);
    return view('tabla')->with($data);
```

Envio los datos a la view mediante un array ya que envio más datos, resultados de otras consultas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria $ston["mensaje"] no $mensaje en la valdiacion de isset de la vista

Comment: Gracias, si funciona cuando mi stored arroja datos me muestra mis consultas, pero cuando no hay datos y que va el mensaje no lo muestra solo no se ve nada

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar forelse ejemplo:

```
                @forelse($ston as $stone)
                    {{$stone[0]->PeriodoAct}} <br>
                    {{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($stone[0]->Fecha)) }}<br>
                   {{$stone[0]->Concep}}<br>
                    {{ number_format($stone[0]->Import, 1, '.', '') }}<br>
                    {{$stone[0]->Status}}<br>
                @empty
                 <h1>No hay datos </h1>
                @endforelse
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probare, a ver cómo me va !

Answer (score 0):

En la segunda línea del if() iría:

```
$ston['mensaje'] = $mensaje;
```